# copy files to another directory except ".txt" file extension

Tags: shell, unix, sh, ls, cp

I have many files with different file extensions,so i want to copy all except

> ".txt"

to another directory.

I tried below command to find all possible files with different file extensions except ".txt"

```
ls -lrt /home/updatet/test/ -I "*.txt"
```

and to copy

```
ls -1 /home/updatet/test/ | xargs cp {} demo/
```

Comment: Which shell? Does this really need to support `sh`, or can you use extensions added in bash or ksh?

Comment: BTW, see [why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 1):

#### Using bash extglobs:

See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern#extended_pattern_language for documentation

```
shopt -s extglob
cp /home/updatet/test/!(*.txt) demo/
```

#### Portably:

```
for f in /home/updatet/test/*; do
  case $f in
    *.txt) :;;
    *)     cp "$f" demo/ ;;
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find /home/updatet/test ! -name \*.txt -exec cp {} demo/ \;
```

Comment: `-exec ... {} +` requires the `{}` to be **directly** before the `+`. You need the less-efficient `\;` usage here, unless you're going to rely on GNU cp by using `-exec cp -t demo/ -- {} +`

Comment: Right. s/+/\;/ Will edit answer. Thanks @CharlesDuffy